# Dangers of creating Foreign Keys. nHibernate and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have inherited an old shabby database, and would like to put loads of foreign keys in on existing relationship columns, so that I can use things like nHibernate for relationships.

I am a little inexperienced in the realm of keys, and although I feel I understand how they work, there is some part of me that is fearful, or corrupting the database somehow.

For example, I've come across the concept of "cascade on delete". I don't think there are currently any foreign keys on the database, so I guess this won't affect me... but how can I check to be sure?

What other risks do I need to be aware of?

In a way I'd love to just use nHibernate without foreign keys, but from what I can see this wouldn't be possible?

Comment: Foreign keys are your friend. They protect the integrity of your data.

Comment: you cannot cascade delete except as part of a foreign key realtionship.

Answer (score 4):

NHibernate does not require foreign keys to be present on a database to be used, however I would still recommend adding foreign keys whenever possible as foreign keys are a ***good thing*** they make sure that your database's referential integrity is as it should be.

For example, if I had a `User` and a `Comment` table within my database and I were to delete user 1 who happens to have made two comments, without foreign keys I'd now have two comments without an owner! We obviously do not want this situation to ever occur.

This is where foreign keys come in, by declaring that `User` is a foreign key within `Comment` table our database server will make sure that we can't delete a user unless it there are no comments associated with him or her (anymore).

Introducing foreign keys into a database is a good thing. It will expose existing invalid data. It will keep existing valid data, valid. You might have to perform some data manipulation on tables that have already gone haywire (i.e. create an 'Unknown user' or something similar and update all non-existing keys to point at it, this is a decision that needs to be made after examining the meaning of the data).

It might even cause a few issues initially where an existing application crash if for example it doesn't delete all the data it should do (such as not deleting all comments in my example). But this is a good thing in the long term, as it exposes where things are going wrong and allows you to fix them without the data and database getting into an even worse state in the meantime.

[NHibernate cascades](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) are seperate from foreign keys and are NHibernate's way of allowing you to for example make sure all child objects are deleted when you delete a parent. This for example allows you to make sure that any change you make to your data model does not violate your foreign key relationships (which would cause a database exception and no changes to be applied). Personally I prefer to take care of this myself, but it's up to you whether and how you want to use them.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem of putting foreign keys on a database that was designed without them (which is a indication the orginal database designers were incompetent, so there will be many other problems to fix as well), is that there is close to a 100% chance that you have orphaned data that doesn't have a parent key. You will need to figure out what to do with this data. Some of it can just be thrown out as it is no longer usable in any fashion and is simply wasting space. However if any of it relates to orders or anything financial, you need to keep the data, in which case you may need to define a parent record of "unknown" that you can relate the records to. Find and fix all bad data first, then add the foreign keys.

Use cascade update and cascade delete sparingly as they can lock up your database if a large number of records need to be changed. Additonally, in many cases, you want the delete to fail if existing records exist. You don't want to cascade delete ever through financial records for instance. If deleting the user would delete past orders, that is a very bad thing! If you don't use cascading, you are likely to come across the buggy code that let the data get bad when you can no longer delete or change a record once the key is in place. So test all deleting and updating functionality thoroughly once you have the keys in place.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys formalize relationships in a normalized database. The foreign key constraints you are talking about do things like preventing the creation of duplicate keys or the deletion of a field which defines an entity still being used or referenced. This is called "referential integrity.

I suggest using some kind of modelling tool to draw a so-called ERM or entity-relationship model diagram. This will help you to get an overview of how the data is stored and where changes would be useful.

After you have done this, then you should consider whether or not the data is at a reasonable (say second or third normal form) degree of normalization. Pay particular attention to every entity having a primary key, and that the data completely describes the key. You should also try to remove redundancy and split non-atomic fields into a new table. "Every non-key attribute must provide a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key so help you Codd." If you find the data is not normalized it would be a good time to fix any serious structural problems and/or refactor, if appropriate.

At this point, adding foreign keys and constraints is putting the cart before the horse. Ensure you have data integrity before you try to protect it. You need to do some preparation work first, then constraints will keep your not-so-shabby newly remodeled database in tip-top shape. The constraints will ensure that no one decides to make exceptions to the rules that turn the data into a mess. Take the time to give the data a better organized home now, and put locks on the doors after.